# i want to add ltrim on this query so that i got the data wiht ltrim and also distinct

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
**speciality**
---name
--name
-name
```

so it wont give me distinct values  due to spaces(-) how to use ltrim

```
select distinct split.a.value('.','varchar(100)')as string from (select cast ('<M>' + replace(speciality, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' as xml) as string from health where type='Doctor' and speciality like '%dentist%') as a cross apply String.nodes ('/M') as split(a)
```

Comment: `select distinct REPLACE(split.a.value('.','varchar(100)'), ' ', '') ...` or `select distinct REPLACE(split.a.value('.','varchar(100)'), '-', '')`

Comment: thanks it works but m using ltrim that works for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE`:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369974)**

```
select distinct REPLACE(split.a.value('.','varchar(100)'), '-', '')  as string
from (select cast ('<M>' + replace(speciality, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' as xml) as string 
      from health 
      where type='Doctor' 
        and speciality like '%dentist%') as a 
cross apply String.nodes ('/M') as split(a)
```

or if your data is:

```
**speciality**
   name
  name
 name
```

use just `LTRIM`:

```
select distinct LTRIM(split.a.value('.','varchar(100)'))  as string
from (select cast ('<M>' + replace(speciality, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' as xml) as string 
          from health 
          where type='Doctor' 
            and speciality like '%dentist%') as a 
cross apply String.nodes ('/M') as split(a)
```

Comment: @Niteshkumar If this answer is helpful, consider marking accepting it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)